# Reusing DataGridCell style defined as static resource

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-style

I have the following static resource in my application.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="SummaryCell" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

I want to apply it to each cell in the data grid if `IsSummary` is true. I (naively) tried the following:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSummary}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource SummaryCell}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

I get the following error at runtime:

> **Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies.**

which makes sense, because the data trigger is setting the style of the cell, which is apparently also what the `Datagrid.CellStyle` property is doing.

How can I reuse the static resource within a trigger, or what other approach can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Error makes perfect sense here. Though, I can suggest a workaround here is to ***wrap the DataGrid in ContentControl and apply trigger on it's ControlTemplate***.

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"/>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSummary}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="dataGrid" Property="DataGrid.CellStyle"
                            Value="{StaticResource SummaryCell}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: @Zev Spitz - Does this answer works for you OR still looking for something else?

Comment: I ended up creating a separate static resource with the DataTrigger, and copying the setters.